# How can I determine the action that originated a commit within Gitlab?

Tags: git, shell, github, gitlab

In Github there are environment variables like GITHUB_VIA that expose the action that originated a git commit. In the example below, taken from [here](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/pre-receive-hooks/restrict-master-to-gui-merges.sh), this is used to protect default branches.

Is there something similar for Gitlab? I'm coding a pre-receive hook and I can't find this documented anywhere on Gitlab's doc.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This hook restricts changes on the default branch to those made with the GUI Pull Request Merge button, or the Pull Request Merge API.
#
DEFAULT_BRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)
while read -r oldrev newrev refname; do
  if [[ "${refname}" != "${DEFAULT_BRANCH:=refs/heads/master}" ]]; then
    continue
  else
    if [[ "${GITHUB_VIA}" != 'pull request merge button' && \
          "${GITHUB_VIA}" != 'pull request merge api' ]]; then
      echo "Changes to the default branch must be made by Pull Request. Direct pushes, edits, or merges are not allowed."
      exit 1
    else
      continue
    fi
  fi
done
```

I'm looking for environment variables I could use within the context of a pre-receive on Gitlab, such as [these ones](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/admin/policies/enforcing-policy-with-pre-receive-hooks/creating-a-pre-receive-hook-script#available-for-pushes-from-the-web-interface-or-api) on GHE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the information that is normally exposed in [git pre-receive hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive), GitLab does provide some [additional environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html#environment-variables-available-to-server-hooks). The closest thing to `GITHUB_VIA` would be `GL_PROTOCOL`, which can tell you some information like if a push was made using http/ssh or the web UI. The value of this variable will be either `http` `ssh` or `web` accordingly.

So, in your case you might do something like:

```bash
if [[ "$GL_PROTOCOL" != "web" ]]; then
  echo "Changes to the default branch must be made by Pull Request. Direct pushes, edits, or merges are not allowed."
  exit 1
fi
```

It is worth mentioning, however, that GitLab has controls for this use case directly in the project settings in [protected branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html). For example, you can create a protected branch rule that prohibits pushes to the branch and only allows changes via an MR. So you should be able to achieve the same effect in GitLab without a pre-receive hook.

Comment: Thanks @sytech. This is exactly what I was looking for. 

The example I provided is not related to what I'm trying to achieve but thanks for taking the time to provide a suggestion anyway.